# How to only use provider in a listview?

Tags: flutter

I have a **Listview** inside which there are containers and each container has an image and another container which consists of two buttons. I want to change the icon of the button whenever it is clicked. But when the button is clicked, every button inside every containers get changed. How can I make only the selected button icon change?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:group_project/data/data.dart';
import 'package:group_project/models/products.dart';
import 'package:group_project/ui/size_config.dart';
import 'package:group_project/constants.dart';
import 'package:group_project/widgets/custom_button_widget.dart';
import 'package:group_project/widgets/providerexample.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProductCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Products products;
  ProductCard({this.products});
  @override
  _ProductCardState createState() => _ProductCardState();
}

class _ProductCardState extends State<ProductCard> {
  void chatWithSeller() {}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final changeIcon = Provider.of<ProviderExample>(context);
    return Container(
//      color: Colors.red,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.6 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // This container contains the product image.
            Container(
              height: 210 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
              width: 200 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(
                  widget.products.images[0],
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
//                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(1.0), BlendMode.softLight),
              )),
            ),

            //This container contains the description of the image
            Flexible(
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Container(
                height: 100 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                width: 200 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),

                        // Title and price tag of the product
                        child: Container(
//                              color: Colors.red,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  widget.products.isUsed == true
                                      ? '${widget.products.productName} (Used)'
                                      : '${widget.products.productName} (New)',
                                  style: productDescTextStyle,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Rs. ${widget.products.price}',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      //Buttons
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6.6, 0, 6.6, 16.6) *
                            SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                        height: 53.0 * SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
                        // color: Colors.yellow,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal:
                                        5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                                child: CustomButton(
                                  icon: EvaIcons.shoppingCartOutline,
                                  btnName: 'Chat with Seller',
                                  height: 26.0 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                  width: 60 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                  buttonColor: Colors.blue,
                                  splashColor: Colors.white,
                                  iconColor: Colors.white,
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  btnTextSize: 6.0,
                                  iconSize: 14.0,
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  btnBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                  onTap: chatWithSeller,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 5,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal:
                                        5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                                child: Consumer<ProviderExample>(
                                  builder: (context, value, child) => CustomButton(
                                    icon: changeIcon.isClicked
                                        ? EvaIcons.heart
                                        : EvaIcons.heartOutline,
                                    btnName: 'Add To Watchlist',
                                    height: 26.0 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                    width: 80 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                    buttonColor: Colors.white,
                                    splashColor: Colors.blue,
                                    iconColor: Colors.blue,
                                    textColor: Colors.blue,
                                    btnTextSize: 6.0,
                                    iconSize: 14.0,
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    btnBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      if(changeIcon.isClicked) {
                                        changeIcon.isClicked = false;
                                      } else {
                                        changeIcon.isClicked = true;
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey[400],
              spreadRadius: 0,
              offset: Offset(0, 1),
              blurRadius: 5.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This product card is called in another class**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:group_project/models/models.dart';
import 'package:group_project/screens/product_details.dart';
import 'package:group_project/ui/size_config.dart';
import 'package:group_project/widgets/product_card.dart';

class ProductCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
  final Size size;
  final List<Products> products;
  final String category;
  final String productTypeText;
  ProductCarousel(
      {@required this.products, @required this.size, @required this.category, this.productTypeText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Main Container
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: 340 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
      ),
      width: size.width, // Takes total width.
       color: Colors.grey[50],
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
//              color: Colors.blue,
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Text(
                  productTypeText,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: products.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
//          Checks if the products are of same category
                if (products[index].category != category) {
                  if (index < products.length) {
                    index++;
                    return Container();
                  } else {
                    return Container();
                  }
                } else {

                  //This container wraps the containers containing image and desc
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print(Products().views);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ProductDetailsPage(
                            product: products[index],
                        ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                      child: ProductCard(
                      products: products[index],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Provider - rebuild list item instead of list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215357/flutter-provider-rebuild-list-item-instead-of-list-view)

Comment: This one is a bit different than mine - @RonakPatel

Comment: you can use ```Provider.of<ProviderClassName>(context)``` on the Custom button